# When bootstrapping a new node into a cassandra ring where will be the new data will be inserted if RF is 1?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, bootstrapping, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1

As of my understanding when you add a new node to a ring with virtual nodes enabled it will be assigned some token ranges and data will be streamed to new node from existing nodes in the ring. When this bootstrapping process is going on, the new node will serve writes and not reads.
   For suppose while this process is going on, if new data has to be inserted in the token range of new node with replication of 1 will this be written to both old node and new node having that token range or will it be written to new node. If it is written only to new node and a request for the newly inserted data comes which node will serve the read request as the new node has not completely joined the ring.

Comment: It gets written to both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When joining a new node in Cassandra the node will not fully become the owner of the new tokens in the ring for either read or write operations until it has had its new data fully streamed to it.  In the process you describe the data will still be written to the Original node (A) owning that token range until the new node (B) has been fully loaded with the data.  At this point node B will broadcast a message stating that it is now the owner of the new token ranges and all future R/W requests will be directed away from A to B.

Comment: Can u add some references ?